# Make Ansible module use /etc/ansible/hosts instead of IP address

Tags: ansible-playbook, drac

I have this Dell iDRAC management module I'm trying to use.

For some bizarre reason it seems to demand an IP address instead of a respecting the hosts: directive. Here's the example I have been given:

```
- hosts: idracs
  connection: local
  name: Check LC Ready Status
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Check LC Ready Status
    dellemc_get_lcstatus:
       idrac_ip:   "{{ idrac_ip }}"
       idrac_user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
       idrac_pwd:  "{{ idrac_pwd }}"
```

I can't see how to make idrac_ip into a variable. Is /etc/ansible/hosts what I should be using or should I create another(different) inventory object?

Comment: I don't know if Ansible can gather facts about iDRAC devices. I don't know what OS they run.

Comment: You want it to come from the inventory, but how is the ip defined in the inventory? Is it just ansible_hostname, or have you stored it in another variable.  It would help if you gave us an example of what you have in your inventory.

Comment: Which inventory are you talking about? 
I do not have IP addresses in /etc/ansible/hosts. I have fqdns in the hosts file.

Comment: Do the fqdns correctly resolve to an IP address?  If yes, I would bet you should be able to use `idrac_ip:: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"`.  If you have the same user/password for all your systems you could use a group_vars, or define those in the play, or task.

Comment: The fqdns do resolve properly. I wouldn't consider using them if they didn't. 
Yes the same credentials work on all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you need to define these facts for each host yourself.

It appears you're using the [Dell EMC OpenManage Ansible modules](https://github.com/dell/dellemc-openmanage-ansible-modules). The way these examples are designed, they appear to expect the variables to come from host facts. So you can just define `host_vars` for each host. For example, you might create `host_vars/myserver.example.com/idrac.yml`:

```
idrac_ip: 10.208.35.6
idrac_user: root
idrac_pw: calvin
```

Of course, you could get the variables elsewhere for some of the other operations you might perform, e.g. from static facts set on each host or from a dynamic inventory script, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. There is a host_vars dir in the repo. I'll try using that.

Comment: I never got this to work.